# find_element in Selenium (Python with BeautifulSoup) is not finding all elements from a certain class in a website. Why is that?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to apply web scraping to get all the discounts in a website (www.ofertop.pe).
I have a script that happens to crawl a website, using Selenium together with BS4 and Requests (Python 3.5+) to list all the subsections and then scrape each subsection (which is a grid with several discounts).
The website goes as follow: www.ofertop.pe.

I have analyzed the website HTML and found there is a tree of sections inside the element "accesoSeccion". From that, I find all the elements nivel2" in order to get all the subsections inside the first section map. You can see the code following here:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'/usr/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver') 

def load_html(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} 
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

soup = load_html("https://ofertop.pe/")
lista_urls = ['https://ofertop.pe' + c.find('a')['href'] for c in soup.find('ul', {'id':'accesoSeccion'}).find_all('li')]
categories = {c.split('/')[-1]:c for c in lista_urls}
sp = load_html(categories["bienestar-y-salud"]) #can be any section, since nivel2 repeats in each of them
subcats = [[ss.find("a")["href"] for ss in s.find_all("li")][1:] for s in sp.findAll("div", {"class":"nivel2"})]
subcats_flat = [x for y in subcats for x in y]
```

When I print categories I get:

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/salon-de-belleza

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/gastronomia

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/entretenimiento

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/viajes-y-turismo

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/servicios

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/estetica

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/productos

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/bienestar-y-salud

The subcategories (stored as a flat list in subcategories_flat) are the categories inside the menu at the left side of each category. For example, for the last category (bienestar y salud) you can get the following subsections:

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/bienestar-y-salud/dental

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/bienestar-y-salud/gimnasio-fitness

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/bienestar-y-salud/otros-bienestar-salud

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/bienestar-y-salud/spa-y-relajacion

https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/bienestar-y-salud/salud

Note: I delete the first subcategory since it's equivalent to the union of every remaining subcategory.

After this, I iterate over all the subsections to get the discounts. Using the following loop:

```
df_final_discounts = pd.DataFrame()
for x in subcats_flat:
    url = "https://ofertop.pe" + x
    df = category_scraping(url)
    df["segmento"] = url.split("/")[-2]
    df["subsegmento"] = url.split("/")[-1]
    df_final_discounts = pd.concat([df_final_discounts, df])
```

The code that analyze each subsection and gets all the elements is:

```
def category_scraping(url_discounts):
    df_final = pd.DataFrame()
    driver.implicitly_wait(random.randrange(4))
    while url_discounts != '':
        driver.get(url_discounts)
        #print(url_discounts)
        try:
            driver.implicitly_wait(random.randrange(3))
            url_discounts = driver.find_element_by_id('tripleBasic').find_element_by_xpath("//a[@rel='next']").get_attribute("href")
        except:
            url_discounts = ''
        print(url_discounts)    
        #Already used this one but it doesn't get 100% of discounts either
        #df = pd.DataFrame([get_discount_window(c) for c in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("prod_track")])
        df = pd.DataFrame([get_discount_window(c) for c in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//article[contains(@class, 'prod_track')]")])
        df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df])
        #print(driver.page_source)

    return df_final
```

Reviewing the HTML from every subsection (for example https://ofertop.pe/descuentos/estetica/rostro-y-piel), I can see that the discounts are produced using Embedded Javascript and they are article objects with the class prod_track, therefore I use Selenium to get all those elements. However, whenever I ran the script, I get values different to the ones I see on a normal browser (and with my Selenium driver browser too). Currently, I'm getting around 600 different discounts, but the website Ofertop has around 1600.